# Debounce in lodash runs only once or never

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, lodash

I am trying to limit the number of function execution in my JavaScript code. Lodash is loaded.

In my HTML I have this:

`<input onkeyup="_.debounce(doIt, 1000);" type="text" value="" />`

In JS I have this:

```
function doIt() {
  console.log('done');
}
```

Now I would expect that while I type inside his input the console.log with output "done" every 1 second no matter how fast I type - or do nothing if I stop typing.

The problem is that it's working only once (the "done" string is written out only once) and then it stops. I have tried to change onkeyup to oninput but then it don't even work once.

How to make it work?

Comment: _.debounce creates a debounced function that delays invoking the original function. so it only will run once. What you are searching for is _.throttle: https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle. Throttle creates a throttled function that limits the rate at which the original function can be invoked, instead of _.debounce delaying. As long as you type something into your input field _.throttle will run your function every 1s (1000ms),

Comment: no I do NOT want to continuously triger while I am typing. I want the function trigger 1 second after I stop typing. So, if i type continuously for 3 seconds trigger wuold run 3x but debounce only once after I finished typing. I know what is the difference between debounce and trigger, that's not my problem. I solved it without lodash by writing my own function. Although it was quite tricky but it works. The docs for lodash are heavy jquery. Who uses jquery in 2023 though?